# static code analysis for dynamic import of modules in js/ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have a code where I lazy import certain modules depending on conditions.

```
case ClientWidgetTypes.HAPPY_WIDGET:
            widgetClass = require('./widget/HappyWidget').default;
            break;
```

Suppose now if I remove the HappyWidget.js/ts file from the project there should be lint in place to tell me its not a valid path or the ts compile should fail. I am unable to achieve either. It would be helpful if I can set tslint or eslint or some kind of rule in ts compilation for it to fail.

We are using ES-6 in case it helps.